# Python speech recognition slowing down

Tags: python, speech-recognition, chatbot, speech

I have developed a new program to speak to my chatbot. It works very well, but there is one strange issue I can't seem to figure out. Every time the process repeats (the console outputs listening and does speech recognition), it slows down. The 1st go is quick, the 2nd a little slower, the 3rd slow, and then it just gets too slow to respond from there on. Please help me figure out what syntax could be causing this.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    while True:
        print("say something")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("Text:"+r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-us', show_all=False));
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Do you restart the script or keep going? are you emptying the source variable? why is `with` outside the `while`? Is this the full code of the recognition part of your code?

Comment: Hi this is my complete code, And I am not restarting it is keep going but after 3 iterations it is very slow and I tried writing "with" inside inside "while" still same problem

Answer (score 2):

It's the problem with loop order. I just included `r = sr.Recognizer()` and `with sr.Microphone() as source:` inside `while`  and it is working fine and no delay in response.

Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Yeah Thank you Alex